# C# Xamarin speech recognition in the background [Android]

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, speech-recognition, speech-to-text

Is this possible to make an app what will recognize if I tell eg. "top" or "back" in the background and will start some actions when find if I tell that.

I tested speech recognition when click on button and it shows google voice recognition.

Can I do that without click on button, with recognition in real time in the background?

Comment: Have your read [this](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/platform_features/speech/)?

Comment: I used sample speech to text from this site, which is speech to text after push a button.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is very possible, if you are using google voice recognition on android, what you have to do to get rid of the clicking button is to make your own SpeechRecognizer class and inherit it.

Here is the code I use on my apps :

```
public class CustomRecognizer : Java.Lang.Object, IRecognitionListener, TextToSpeech.IOnInitListener
{
private SpeechRecognizer _speech;
private Intent _speechIntent;


public string Words;


public CustomRecognizer(Context _context)
{
    this._context = _context;
    Words = "";
    _speech = SpeechRecognizer.CreateSpeechRecognizer(this._context);
    _speech.SetRecognitionListener(this);
    _speechIntent = new Intent(RecognizerIntent.ActionRecognizeSpeech);
    _speechIntent.PutExtra(RecognizerIntent.ExtraLanguageModel, RecognizerIntent.LanguageModelFreeForm);
    _speechIntent.PutExtra(RecognizerIntent.ActionRecognizeSpeech, RecognizerIntent.ExtraPreferOffline);
    _speechIntent.PutExtra(RecognizerIntent.ExtraSpeechInputCompleteSilenceLengthMillis, 1000); 
    _speechIntent.PutExtra(RecognizerIntent.ExtraSpeechInputPossiblyCompleteSilenceLengthMillis, 1000);
    _speechIntent.PutExtra(RecognizerIntent.ExtraSpeechInputMinimumLengthMillis, 1500);
}

void startover()
{
    _speech.Destroy();
    _speech = SpeechRecognizer.CreateSpeechRecognizer(this._context);
    _speech.SetRecognitionListener(this);
    _speechIntent = new Intent(RecognizerIntent.ActionRecognizeSpeech);
    _speechIntent.PutExtra(RecognizerIntent.ExtraSpeechInputCompleteSilenceLengthMillis, 1000);
    _speechIntent.PutExtra(RecognizerIntent.ExtraSpeechInputPossiblyCompleteSilenceLengthMillis, 1000);
    _speechIntent.PutExtra(RecognizerIntent.ExtraSpeechInputMinimumLengthMillis, 1500);
StartListening();
}
public void StartListening()
{
    _speech.StartListening(_speechIntent);
}

public void StopListening()
{
    _speech.StopListening();
}

public void OnBeginningOfSpeech()
{

}

public void OnBufferReceived(byte[] buffer)
{
}

public void OnEndOfSpeech()
{

}

public void OnError([GeneratedEnum] SpeechRecognizerError error)
{
    Words = error.ToString();
    startover();
}

public void OnEvent(int eventType, Bundle @params)
{
}

public void OnPartialResults(Bundle partialResults)
{
}

public void OnReadyForSpeech(Bundle @params)
{
}

public void OnResults(Bundle results)
{

    var matches = results.GetStringArrayList(SpeechRecognizer.ResultsRecognition);
    if (matches == null)
        Words = "Null";
    else
        if (matches.Count != 0)
        Words = matches[0];
    else
        Words = "";

    //do anything you want for the result
    }
    startover();
}

public void OnRmsChanged(float rmsdB)
{

}

public void OnInit([GeneratedEnum] OperationResult status)
{
    if (status == OperationResult.Error)
        txtspeech.SetLanguage(Java.Util.Locale.Default);
}}
```

To use it on your activity, just create the class and call **StartListening()**